# how to scroll horizontal scroll view without animation

Tags: android, animation, scrollview

The problem is that I'm using the `fullScroll()` and `scrollTo()` functions to scroll but it is animated and I need it happen without user observation.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

```
hScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
    }
});
```

Comment: try hScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_LEFT);

Comment: thanks, but I tried it before and I have the same problem!

Comment: But what's wrong with animation?  I would think the user experience is better if they see the scrolling rather than just a jump to another location.

Answer (score 7):

Use this

```
// Disable the animation First
hScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false);
// Now scroll the view
hScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
// Now enable the animation again if needed
hScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false);` before running the `Runnable` command, this will give you the desired output

```
        // Set smooth scrolling to false
        hScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false);

        // Then call the fullScroll method
        hScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        });
```